# round off double value in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there any spring boot attribute to round off double value

For example

```
@roundOfDouble(Any Parameter ?)
Double amount;     1500.95 -> 1501.00
```

If null, `then 0.00`

any suggestions ?

Comment: @BroscR, I'm looking for any spring attribute which can be used directly as attribute above amount parameter. Not looking for any custom code

Answer (score 4):

This is a general problem with `doubles` and if you have such requirement then `double` should be avoided. Maybe switching to `BigDecimal` could help your use case. It will certainly give you flexibility to put some combination to round off over doubles.

For example

```
public class Invoice {

    @DecimalMin(value = "0.0", inclusive = false)
    @Digits(integer=3, fraction=2)
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String description;

    public Invoice(BigDecimal price, String description) {
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

[Check this out](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-bigdecimal-validation)